# child process takes control when using subprocess

Tags: python, linux, process, gstreamer, tk-toolkit

I am using the tk library to develop a GUI. Upon a button press, the following function is executed

```
def playvid(self,x):
    if x == 1:
        cmd = 'gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! autovideosink'
    elif x == 2:
        cmd = 'gst-launch -e videomixer name=mix ! ffmpegcolorspace ! autovideosink videotestsrc pattern=1 ! video/x-raw-yuv, framerate=5/1, width=320, height=180 ! videobox border-alpha=0 top=0 left=0 ! mix. videotestsrc pattern=15 ! video/x-raw-yuv, framerate=5/1, width=320, height=180 ! videobox border-alpha=0 top=0 left=-320 ! mix.'
    else:
        cmd = ''
    self.a = 0
    self.proc1 = subprocess.Popen(cmd,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,shell=True)
    print self.proc1.pid
    self.cmd = "kill -9 " + str(self.proc1.pid + 2)
    with Input(keynames='curses') as input_generator:
        for e in input_generator:
            if e == 's':
                os.system(self.cmd)
                return
```

This transfers control to the child process and any button click on the GUI gets executed only after the child process is killed. How do I continue to use the GUI even after the child process has been created?

Comment: `str(self.proc1.pid + 2)` what? you're performing arithmetic on process ids?

Comment: yes, that is to get the gstreamer window's pid.

Comment: Be aware that gst-launch is only a debugging tool and the automatically created windows by the sinks are also just for debugging purposes.

If you want to have control over the windows, you need to write code in you application: you can use the python bindings. There you would then create the windows yourself in one way or another, and tell the sinks to render into these windows instead of having them create their own windows.